# Channel close by rabbitmq server and exception is not received by consumer

Tags: go, rabbitmq, channel

I am using GoLang, Rabbitmq server closing the connection with below error but consumer never receives the close message "channel is closed" as per the code.

```
# rabbitmqctl version
3.12.1
# 

PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc guide to learn more
```

Below piece of code create channels and wait for message in respective chan.

```
    amqpConn, amqpChannel, err := connectToAmqp(ctx, config, logger)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
consumeChan, err := amqpChannel.Consume("TestQueue", "", false, false, false, false, nil)
    chanClosedChan := amqpChannel.NotifyClose(makeAmqpErrorChan())
    connClosedChan := amqpConn.NotifyClose(makeAmqpErrorChan())

    for {
        select {
        case amqpErr := <-chanClosedChan:
           logger.Error(ctx, "channel is closed")
        case amqpErr := <-connClosedChan:
           logger.Error(ctx, "closed rabbitmq connection")
        case <-ctx.Done():
            logger.Info(ctx, "Closing rabbitmq connection")
            err := amqpChannel.Close()
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error(ctx, "Failed to cleanly close rabbitmq connection", field.Error(err))
            }
            return
        case amqpMessage, ok := <-consumeChan:
            if ok {
            logger.Debug(ctx, "Received amqpMessage message", field.Any("AmqpMessage", amqpMessage))
            }
        }
    }
```

**Strangely** after moving the case amqpMessage, ok := <-consumeChan: to a different go routine I was able to receive the "channel is closed" error.
Althoug it has resolved my problem but I an not sure how moving to different go routine the channel exception started to receive on the consumer side.

The code changes are

```
....
go handleConsumerChannel(ctx,consumeChan)
    for {
        select {
        case amqpErr := <-chanClosedChan:
           logger.Error(ctx, "channel is closed")
        case amqpErr := <-connClosedChan:
           logger.Error(ctx, "closed rabbitmq connection")
        case <-ctx.Done():
            logger.Info(ctx, "Closing rabbitmq connection")
            err := amqpChannel.Close()
            if err != nil {
                logger.Error(ctx, "Failed to cleanly close rabbitmq connection", field.Error(err))
            }
            return
        }
    }
...

func handleConsumerChannel(ctx context.Context,consumeChan <-chan amqp.Delivery) {
    for {
        select {
        case amqpMessage, ok := consumeChan:
            if ok {
                logger.Debug(ctx, "Received amqpMessage message", field.Any("AmqpMessage", amqpMessage))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original version of your code, you are blocking your main goroutine with your `for` block busy waiting for messages from the amqp message channel.

Moving the case `amqpMessage, ok := <-consumeChan` into a separate goroutine allowed the main select block to handle channel closure events and errors more promptly. In the original code, when message processing was inside the same select block, it delayed the handling of error cases.

By separating message handling into a goroutine, it stopped competing with error handling for execution time and error cases are processed as expected.

Comment: I was looking for an explaination only and you have rightly explained looks like, can you help me on getting any doc or resource where this type of situation handeling is present?

Comment: I think this is a language-agnostic situation. You can check docs about concurrency/busy waiting and the golang docs about goroutines

Comment: You mentioned it delayed the handling of error cases. but in my case I was not receiving the error message at all until I moved that case out to another goroutine. And now another strange thing started to happen where the case which I moved to another routine that is now not getting the message, but error is now getting received, it's like it's flipped error is receving but now messsage are not :(

Comment: Looks like that is not the right explaination, select ideally don't priortize any channel in GO. In my case actually a channe is waiting for receive message that is why it's getting blocked. when I removed that unecessary channel, even without moving to other go-routine things started to work

Answer (score 0):

The issue here not resolved because I have moved the case amqpMessage, ok := <-consumeChan to another go routine. It's resovled because there was channel which was waiting to receive and therefore halting the go-routine that is why no exception for channel or connection was getting received.